# Map a string with a function on Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, mapping

Is it possible to map a string to a function using TS.
For example :

```
this.keyBinding = new Map<string, Function>();
    this.keyBinding
        .set('Backspace', this.handleBackspace)
        .set('Delete', this.handleDelete)
```

I tried to execute it using:

```
this.keyBinding.get('Backspace');
```

but nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.get` will return a function, so if you want to run the function, you must invoke it:

```
this.keyBinding.get('Backspace')();
```

If the string being passed in may not exist in the Map, check that it exists first:

```
const fn = this.keyBinding.get('Backspace');
if (fn) fn();
```

If the `handleBackspace` and `handleDelete` methods depend on having a `this` context, then you'll need to account for that as well:

```
this.keyBinding
        .set('Backspace', () => this.handleBackspace())
        .set('Delete', () => this.handleDelete());
```